# Map view does not render full SVG, but layers pane and print layout does?

Tags: qgis-3, mac, svg

In map view where I want to do all design and small changes the SVGs for "MELLANTID" does not render the added outline, only original size. The SVG for "SJUKVARD" only renders the left half of the SVG, only the drink symbol and not the medical.

I searched this site, Google and tried everything and still can't figure out why the SVGs render wrong in map view. They are correct in the layers pane and when exporting/print layout.

[image: Layer pane, correct]

[image: Print Layout, correct]

[image: Map view, not correct]

Comment: How is the icon size defined? Is it scale-based, or in map units, or in mm?

Comment: @csk right now map units, have tried mm as well.

Comment: I asked because it looks like on the map canvas, the svg is being scaled down too far. If the svg is in map units, it has to be re-scaled every time you change the map scale. So I wonder if QGIS is taking a shortcut to speed up map rendering. Does it help to choose a fixed icon size, or does the issue still occur when the icon size is in mm?

Comment: @csk Good suggestion but unfortunately the issue is the same with all size units.

Comment: Now I'm thinking this is a bug, possibly the same as [this issue](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21285).